# create 1-D numpy.ndarray instead of 2 dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, classification

I am trying to do a classification using Python.
I have some input columns (let k variables) and one output column.

```
Let inputfeatures 
  = array([[ 0, 0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 1, 0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 1, 0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
           ...,
           [ 0, 0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 1, 0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 0, 0,  0, ...,  0,  1,  0]], dtype=int64)
target_array
= array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

I am fitting the model as,

```
trainedModel = model.fit(inputfeatures,target_array)
```

The classifier I am using needs *Data Phenotypes for all data instances are represented by a 1 dimensional numpy.ndarray of length n*.

I am getting no errors while fitting, since the target_array is 1 dimensional numpy.ndarray of length n.

Suppose, I need to have *two output variables*, how can I create a 1 dimensional numpy.ndarray of length n to fit the model?

I just tried as given below:

```
target_array=data[data.columns[data.columns.isin(['var1', 'var2'])]].values
target_array
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

But it is 2 dimensional. How to make it 1 dimensional numpy.ndarray of length n?

Comment: Are you trying to do a multivariate forecast (where the target is more than 1-dimensional)?  It is possible and there are several approaches to do that, but it requires some careful thinking. It's not just some mechanical setup question.

Comment: Yes multiple variables are there as target... Currently I have var1 as output variable. I donot know how to add var1 and var 2 as a single 1-D numpy.ndarray. I need to use a particular classifier and it needs the target variable as 1-D numpy.ndarray.

Comment: You can't transform a 2D target output into a 1D one. Think about it: if your 2D output distribution is an L-shape surface, then what would the 1D projection be, and how would that be appropriate for a classifier to target?

Comment: Okay Got it, So I think I should go for Multi-class Endpoints... with 4 values in target variable instead of binary....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply transform an `n`-dimensional label (or "target output") into a 1-dimensional one.  In some cases where the output distribution is an `m`-dimensional manifold embedded into an `n`-dimensional space, you may try to do a projection first (including, if necessary, a non-linear projection), but you have to think *very carefully* about what you want your classifier or your regressor to learn.

One simple strategy is to have a dedicated learner per output label. This will "work" in the mechanical sense that you'll be able to forecast an output for any input that is consistent with the input distribution. But it will ignore the possible interactions between the output variables. Imagine an 2D output distribution like this:

[image]

Two learners, each seeing only one of the output variables, won't have a chance to learn about that output structure and will likely (and wrongly) forecast some output points in the positive quadrant that should be empty.

One strategy is to learn a first variable `y_0` from your input `X`. Then learn a second variable `y_1` after augmenting your input `X` with the forecast `y_0_hat` from the first classifier. And so on.

Generally speaking, check out:

- [Wikipedia: Multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification)
- [scikit-learn's multiclass](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), especially the "multioutput" classes which are what I believe you are seeking.